# Inheriting prop style in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

How to apply a styling prop, such as the **outlined** prop in `<v-btn outlined>My Button</v-btn>` in Vuetify to multiple tags without the need to set it to each occurrence. For example for all occurrences within a:

- `<v-app>`
- `<template>`
- `<v-card>`

Creating a CSS class that makes an 'outline' (in this case) would obviously work, but kind of defeats the purpose of the prop.

Or, alternatively, could default props be set somewhere, so they don't need to be declared?

Answer (score 0):

```
// some already existing component, you need to get it somehow
// most likely via `import <something-to-import>`
let theExternalComponent = {
  props: { wrap: { default: false, type: Boolean } },
  template: "<li>wrap:{{wrap}}</li>"
};
// this simulates the global registration
Vue.component("v-some-external-component", theExternalComponent);

// -- lets start --

// lets extend that component - and overwrite the default prop for wrap
let extendedExternalwithOtherDefaults = {
  extends: theExternalComponent,
  mixins: [{ props: { wrap: { default: true } } }],
};

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { "v-my-customized-component": extendedExternalwithOtherDefaults }
});
```

html ([pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) actually but that does not matter here)

```
div(id="app")
  ul
    v-some-external-component

    v-some-external-component(wrap)

    v-my-customized-component
    // now defaults to wrap:true

    v-my-customized-component(:wrap="false") 
    // you can still set the wrap to false if required
```

output

```
wrap:false
wrap:true
wrap:true
wrap:false
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLxbEW